# What is the function of a sweep cable?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, airfoil, ultralight

This is Goat3 ultralight with sweep cables,what is the fuction of these sweep cables?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To keep the wings straight.

If you remove them there is very little to prevent the wing from rotating around the vertical axis.

All the other cables are attached to the king post or the seat. This cannot provide the leverage needed to counteract the wing yawing relative to the seat.

Comment: Okay but I've observed that majority of the ultralights I've seen (images) don't actually have sweep cables,so how do they keep their wings "straight ".

Comment: The torque needs to be counteracted somewhere, It is possible to do it entirely internal to the wing mount, or using the chord length for leverage. Which one to pick depends on design decisions.